# set focus on any item of listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview which contains textviews as its elements.

1. Now I want the first item of the list to be automatically focused when I launch the application
2. How can I set the focus on any item of the list when I click on the some other view for example a button?

Answer (score 11):

Setting selection and setting focus are two different things. If you want to just setSelection to some item then you can use below code.

```
    mListView.setSelection(position);
```

But this definitely does not mean the `Listview` is focused.For focussing you have to use

```
    mListView.requestFocus();
```

For changing focus on click of a button you can place the code on `onClick()` of the button.

Answer (score 4):

ListView has a [setSelected](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection(int)) method that takes the index of the item in the list.

Comment: Hi 
   but selected listitem is same as focused listitem?

Comment: AFAIK selection is not the same as focus.

Comment: Hey Robby, what does `setItemsCanFocus(boolean)` mean?

Answer (score 2):

for me the problem was solved by

```
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Comment: Then how to enable onItemClick for Listview? Because in this case we need to write separate code for click individual item view.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I was in the same situation. I wanted to be able to control the focus of the listview programmatically with buttons .

One solution is to deal with the `setFocusableInTouchMode`, but I've never achieved to make it work.

The other solution is to forget about the focus and use a checkable listview. First set your listview to "single choice mode" in XML or in java : `Mylistview.setChoiceMode(1)`

Then you'll be able to check any item you want with `Mylistview.setItemChecked(position, true)`

So when you launch the application (OnCreate), use `Mylistview.setItemChecked(0, true)` to check your first item.

Then if you want your button to select the next item for exemple, use :

```
Mylistview.setItemChecked(Mylistview.getCheckedItemPosition() + 1, true)
```

You can specify the look when the item is checked or not and there's different pre-built chekable listviews.

If you want more explanations, see my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview/10791326#10791326)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your ListView should be like this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/my_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:choiceMode="none"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">
    <requestFocus />
</ListView>
```

2. 

```
mListView.setSelection(3); //or any other number
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in my case I was trying to programmatically focus a menu option in a listView to highlight the item and none of these worked for me. This is what worked:

MenuOption model:

```
public class MenuOption {

    public static final int ALL_ITEMS = 0;
    public static final int CATEGORIES = 1;
    public static final int DISCOUNTS = 2;

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private boolean isFocused;

    public MenuOption(int id, String name, String description, boolean isFocused) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.isFocused = isFocused;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public boolean isFocused() {
        return isFocused;
    }

    public void setFocused(boolean focused) {
        isFocused = focused;
    }
}
```

MenuAdapter:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<MenuOption> menuOptions; // Original Values
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private MenuOptionListener listener;
    private Context context;

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MenuOption> menuOptions, MenuOptionListener listener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuOptions = menuOptions;
        this.listener = listener;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuOptions.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView menuName;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_menu_option, null);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.menuName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_name);

        MenuOption option = menuOptions.get(position);
        holder.menuName.setText(option.getName());
        if (option.isFocused()) {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.menu_focus);
            holder.menuName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white));
            holder.menuName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.menu_un_focus);
            holder.menuName.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.black));
            holder.menuName.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        }
        convertView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            if (!option.isFocused()) {
                resetFocus(position);
                listener.onClicked(option);
            }
        });

        return convertView;

    }

    public void resetFocus(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < menuOptions.size(); i++) {
            menuOptions.get(i).setFocused(i == position);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public interface MenuOptionListener {
        void onClicked(MenuOption option);
    }
}
```

And then in your Activity, you can call `menuAdapter.resetFocus(0)`.