# how to change the color in the listview by clicking on the item?

Tags: android, android-listview

So in a [**ListView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) I have tasks for example "**3:00 PM Sunday washing the car**" and After I wash the car I want to click on the task(item) on the ListView and **change the color** so that I know that I have finished that task.

```
   <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/nTask"
      android:background="#FFFFFF" >
   </ListView>
```

Color1.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/selector_state_blue"/>
```

selector_state_blue.xml

```
      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

  <gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#FF91B2FF"
    android:startColor="#4491B2FF" />

  <corners android:radius="10px" />

 </shape>
```

Comment: use a selector http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview/16976534#16976534 check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector

Comment: @Raghunandan thank u,the second link looks helpful..can u give me at least a Vote :)