# Change Custom Listview Item Background Color in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to change Custom `Listview`'s each Item Background Color. So with Adapter, I use `getView()` but It is not working. How to do this ?
**My Code is as below :**

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aaReportData, R.layout.report_card1, new String[] { "Topic" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTopic}) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lightish);
                    return convertView;
                }
            };
```

Comment: Please check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview)

Comment: does you are passing color through Adapter?? or you want any random color??

Comment: I think he wants different color on each item.

Comment: @Aksh, I want same color on each item.

Comment: @Dhaval, I want same color on each item.

Comment: please check your question, you mentioned to change color of each item

Comment: You must be using custom XML layout file for row. Change the background color of the parent layout in that XML file and you're done.

Comment: @Dhaval, yes, I am using custom XML layout file.

Comment: Change the backgroud property of its parent layout, with whatever color or  drawable you want.

Comment: @Dhaval, ur right. but I want some space between first and second item and like that for each list item.

Comment: @JeetenParmar check my answer..use it in your `ListView` it wii give you Gradient effecton List item selection

Comment: @JeetenParmar did u not get a compile time error with this ???

Comment: @JeetenParmar You'll need custom background for that. One that has a white or your preferable color line at the bottom of it. Apply it as background and it will create perception of space between list items. You can create such a background using paint.

Comment: @JeetenParmar check my updated code.. You can use `divider` to separate `ListView` items

Comment: @Dhaval, Its done as per you said. Check my Answer.

Comment: @Aksh, I am already using divider for border in between each List Item.

Comment: @JeetenParmar so whats the problem with divider??

Comment: @JeetenParmar make dividers bachground transparent..

Answer (score 1):

As per @Dhaval said, I defined background color to parent layout and It worked fine. Now, I want some space between each List Item so I used Drawable and set color and border bottom as white for some space.
It is working fine now and I got result as per my requirement. Thank you so much all of you.

Comment: @Dhaval, it is the easiest solution other than using getView().

Answer (score 0):

you should use    **setBackgroundResource()**  method instead of **setBackgroundColor()**

tryout following code

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue)
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, aaReportData, R.layout.report_card1, new String[] { "Topic" }, new int[] { R.id.tvTopic}) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightish);
                return convertView;
            }
        };
```

Comment: I am getting NullPointerException by using this.

Comment: can you say the exact location where exception throws??

Comment: at convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightish);

Comment: do you have R.color.lightish color in your Color.xml file

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding "View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);" this line.. can you check it again with new code

Answer (score 0):

```
convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item, null);
convertView.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.lightish));
```

You should inflate list item view 
use above line to set color to view 
regards.

Comment: list_item stands for what ?

Comment: as you are using SimpleAdapter .... convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item, null); delete this line

Comment: I have tried, it is giving NullPointerException at like of convertView.setBackgroundColor. ...

Comment: convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.report_card1, null);  try this

Answer (score 0):

Use this selector `xml` in you `ListView`:

```
<item>
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
       android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
       android:endColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
       android:angle="270"/>
   </shape>
</item>
```

**Updated:**

Make changes in your `ListView` like:

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="0.3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/productlistselector">
</ListView>
```

You can use `divider` and set its background `transparent` instead of designing new custom Background..