# how to change color of list item when it is selected in listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

i have one main activity class in which i define string array which fetch list from XML file saved in res/value which contain list of item . now i want that when any item selected it color change to yellow . how to do this please help :)

thanks in advance ::)

my two file's are list_data.XML and Main Activity.java

**List_data.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="tias_list">
        <item>About us</item>
        <item> Offered</item>
        <item> year  </item>
        <item>Process</item>
        <item>item1</item>>    
        <item>item2</item>>
        <item>item3</item>>
        <item>item4</item>
        </string-array>
        </resources>
```

**MY Main Activity class code is**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity  {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        String[] tias_list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tias_list);


        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label,tias_list));


        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setCacheColorHint(0);
        lv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);


       lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id) {


            if (position == 0)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
            else if(position == 1)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), lastyear.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 2)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), la.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 3)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),la.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 4)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 5)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 6)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
            else if(position == 7)
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }

          }
       });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter that you are currently using is the Default Adapter. However, now you want to modify it's properties. To do so you'll need to implement a custom adapter - an adapter of your own. Just Google Custom ListView Adapter if you don't know how to do that.

And in that custom adapter, there'll be a getView() method and in the getView() method of the custom adapter check if the position of item is same as the selected item. If yes, set background colour.

Here's a complete answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978159/1239966

Comment: Sorry but i did not understand :( please see my code and give some suggestion

Comment: @ramanrayat you need create custom adapter instead of built in adapter, see http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown

Answer (score 0):

To set color of selected Item use

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

i.e in your code as

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View view,int position, long id) {

    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
  // your code
```

Comment: i am getting this error"The method setBackgroundColor(int) is undefined for the type Object" ..

Comment: @ramanrayat use `setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));`

Comment: now another error "Color cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: hey i already try this and it also work for me but there is one problem it change the color of item to yellow but after that it doest not get back to old color so when i click another item then two item showing yellow color ...sorry for bad English

Comment: is there any way that first it show yellow after that it goes back to old color ??

Answer (score 0):

IN your getView method, you have to do some code over there.

```
int currentPosition=0;



  if (position == currentPosition) {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    } else {
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YOUR DEFAULT COLOR);
}
```

//click item code:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    currentPosition = position;
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            });
```