# Changing ListView Item background bug

Tags: android, listview

When I'm using `parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);` in my `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` it colorizes, but it works strange.

When I click first or second item it colorizes it... and every item away ~five records. Sometimes I've got NullPointerException. Completely weird, because position is unique and it should recieve me appropriate View, but it doesn't.

I saw solution with overriding getView method, but I'm using this adapter in different places. I just want to color clicked item. How to get reference to selected view?

EDIT:

In my adapter class I created:

```
public static int selectedItem = -1;
```

I added this to my overrided getView method:

```
    if(selectedItem == position){
        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
```

In my activity I added that:

```
myAdapter.selectedItem = position;
myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And It doesn't work. Where I do a mistake?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview

Comment: you can try this way
[you can go through this way.click here....][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562051/listview-item-background-via-custom-selector?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's **not a bug** - it's the way ListView re-uses the views to save resources.

So to avoid this behavior you should on every getView() set all **used** attributes for all your views.

**Updated** - to be quite clear
In your particular case it means that you should set color like this:
**1)** In onItemClick() - in your actitivity -  you should remember given position as selected:

```
myAdapter.selectedItem = position
```

**2)** In getView() - in your adapter:

```
if(selectedItem == position)
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
else
    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(0);//or whatever defauld color
```

**Update 2**
If you want to select many items you should use some structure (like HashSet) to hold all the selected items:
1) In your activity class add member:

```
public static HashSet<Integer> mSelectedItems = new HashSet<Integer>();
```

2) In onItemClick() use following to flip selected state:

```
if(mSelectedItems.contains(position))
   mSelectedItems.remove(position);
else 
   mSelectedItems.add(position);
```

3) In getView():

```
   if(MainActivity.mSelectedItems.contains(position))
        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    else
        parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(0);//or whatever defauld color
```

Comment: I don't get your point. Could you post any code? Which attributes?

Comment: A bit. So: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview) link, there is a _mSelectedItem_ variable. Is it a static field of adapter class? I don't get it at all.

Comment: m prefix is somekind of convention for class member variables. In that example they are storing the last selected item position by updating that variable. That's irrelevant for your problem.

Comment: @KurdTt, I've updated code once more using your variable names. The crucial thing - you should add **else** clause to make your code work well

Comment: @sberezin Well, It works, but It colorize only **one** item. I want to colorize many items. When I'm leaving _else_ section It works like before. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

At first read [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) article;

Then use `ViewHolder` pattern;

And try to `setBackgroundColor()` in `onItemClick()` like this:

```
    view.setBackgroundColor(0);//or whatever defauld color
```