# Android setMultiChoiceModeListener and selected item

Tags: android, android-listview

Should I use `setSelected` when `onItemClick` when using `setMultiChoiceModeListener`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, You should not.

When You enter `Multi Choice Mode` (usually it's triggered by long click on a list item) main onItemClick listener will be overriden and all items that will be pressed will be marked as selected.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But how to make color changes when listitem is selected? I've asked that question but nobody gave me an answer.

Comment: @Arnes Do You use standard item.xml, or custom?

Comment: @Arnes anyway. Simpliest way to do so: set android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" to root element of list item xml You use for Your listView.

And I think that answer will be helpful for You: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16976534/3809678

Answer (score 2):

Won't change background color. Root element of list item is RelativeLayout (in my case)?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="#ebebeb"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's Your LIST layout.  You need to set that background parameter to root element of LIST ITEM layout which You inflating in Your adapter to every listView's row.

Comment: If you are using a drawable selector to specify the color, set `android:background="@drawable/list_selector` on the list item layout and then in the selector `item` use `android:state_activated="true"` to identify the background color to use when the item is activated.