# Not able to set action bar background color and selected listview color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-styles, android-menu

i have used the following code:

```
  listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {


                final int checkedCount = listview.getCheckedItemCount();

                mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");



            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

                mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.delete:
            //my delete code
                        mode.finish();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                //
            }
        });
```

mymenu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
        android:title="Delete"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />

</menu>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/TestActionModeStyle</item>

    </style>

    <style name="TestActionModeStyle">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TestTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/TestSubTitleStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TestTitleStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TestSubTitleStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    </style>
```

When i longpress on listview then item is selected and menu is coming with delete button. But i am not able to set the color of that whole menu and event the selected listview item is also not reflected.

Menu background color occus in white and selected listview item is also occurs white color.

So i want to change the menu color and selected item from listview color.

From above code it is not working.

How can i solved this?

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer for your menu part of the question: [How to change the background color of Action Bar's Option Menu in Android 4.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2)

And this answer [Change background color of selected item on a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview), for changing your selected listview item.

Just for completeness here the parts of those questions that are relevant for you:

**For the menu (note they speak about the Actionbar, but the menu is also included):**

> There is an easy way to change the colors in Actionbar Use [ActionBar](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)
>   Generator..

but since you already have a style you only want to update the menu like a bit further in the linked question:

> In the style generator, the relevant setting is Popup color, which
>   affects "Overflow menu, submenu and spinner panel background".
>
> Go on and generate the zip, but out of all the files generated, you
>   only really need one image, menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png, which
>   looks something like this:
>
> [image: menu_dropdown_panel_example.9.png]
>
> So, add the different resolution versions of it to res/drawable-*.
>   (And perhaps rename them to menu_dropdown_panel.9.png.)
>
> Then, as an example, in res/values/themes.xml you would have the
>   following, with android:popupMenuStyle and android:popupBackground
>   being the key settings.
>
> ```
> <style name="MyAppActionBarTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
>     <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
>     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar</item>
> </style>
>
> <!-- The beef: background color for Action Bar overflow menu -->
> <style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
>     <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel</item>
> </style>
>
> <!-- Bonus: if you want to style whole Action Bar, not just the menu -->
> <style name="MyApp.ActionBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
>     <!-- Blue background color & black bottom border -->
>     <item name="android:background">@drawable/blue_action_bar_background</item>
> </style>
> ```

**For the listview:**

> You can keep track the position of the current selected element:
>
> ```
> OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {
>
>     @Override
>     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
>             mSelectedItem = position;
>             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> And override the getView method of your adapter:
>
> ```
> @Override
> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>     final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);
>
>     if (position == mSelectedItem) {
>         // set your color
>     }
>
>     return view;
> }
> ```

Comment: But i have style with No actionbar.  i cant change the basetheme.

Comment: True you have to read a bit further on that question. I will update my answer.

Comment: i had tried this. But still i didnt get the solution.