# Change background color and Font type to bold on item selected in Listview

Tags: android, listview, focus, background-color, lostfocus

What i have tried :

listview_selector_focussed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
android:startColor="#008000"
android:endColor="#00FF00"
android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

listview_selector_pressed.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
android:startColor="#800000"
android:endColor="#FF0000"
android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

listview_selector.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
android:state_focused="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_focused" />

<item
android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed" />

</selector>
```

listview layout :

```
<ListView

android:listSelector="@color/listview_selector"
/>
```

- I have tried this much.. but un-fortunately this thing wont work
- I want to change the listview row color when i click and when i click on another row previous row must be deselected and regain original state

Adapter class :

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context ctx;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    TextView tvA, tvB;
    String a, b;

    String out;

    ListViewAdapter(Context ctx, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {

        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.arraylist = arraylist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arraylist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        tvA = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvA);
        tvB = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvB);




        tvA.setText(arraylist.get(position).get("a"));



        a = arraylist.get(position).get("a");
        b = arraylist.get(position).get("b");



        return itemView;
    }
```

listview adapter layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvA"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:minLines="2"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#0052a5"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_large" />


    <TextView
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#0052a5" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you using an adapter to fill your listView?

Comment: yes i am using adapter to fill listview

Comment: can you please post the adapter class?

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: set a on item click listener and change the background and font.. the listener will give u the view/adapter from that extract the tvA and tvB

Answer (score 0):

try to something like my code

```
public class ReportActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView listview;
    Context mContext;

    DatabaseHandler dbHandler;

    ArrayList<ReportModel> mlist;

    ReportAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        mContext=this;


        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        dbHandler=new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        mlist=dbHandler.getAllContacts();
        Collections.reverse(mlist);



            adapter = new ReportAdapter(mContext, R.layout.adapter_layout,
                    mlist);

            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            // Capture ListView item click
            listview.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                                      int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                    // Capture total checked items
                    final int checkedCount = listview.getCheckedItemCount();
                    // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
                    mode.setTitle(checkedCount + " Selected");
                    // Calls toggleSelection method from ListViewAdapter Class
                    adapter.toggleSelection(position);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.delete:
                            // Calls getSelectedIds method from ListViewAdapter Class
                            SparseBooleanArray selected = adapter
                                    .getSelectedIds();
                            // Captures all selected ids with a loop
                            for (int i = (selected.size() - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                                if (selected.valueAt(i)) {
                                    ReportModel selecteditem = adapter
                                            .getItem(selected.keyAt(i));
                                    // Remove selected items following the ids
                                    adapter.remove(selecteditem);
                                    dbHandler.deleteContact(selecteditem.getId());
                                }
                            }
                            // Close CAB
                            mode.finish();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    adapter.removeSelection();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

create xml file activity_main.xml  in menu folder........

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:title="delete"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: how could this be helpful.. plz explain

Answer (score 0):

a good answer might be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16978159/4700782)

You can set the `onItemClick` listener on your listview and in your adapter's `getView()` style the line.

PS: you will need to import the line background layout inside the adapter and set his background :)