# How to Highlight the selected item in Recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to select the value from Recyclerview highlight the selected item. I want to change the bg color and text color and image. Now I am using the following code.

**selector_row**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/store_search_list_item_background"/>
</selector>
```

**In recyclerview on onBindViewHolder** :

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
                    selectedItems.delete(position);
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(false);
                }
                else {
                    selectedItems.put(position, true);
                    holder.itemView.setSelected(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Now I can highlight the selected row. My problem is 
1) When I select another row it's also getting highlighted. I want to highlight only one row. If user select another row previous row should not be highlighted.

2) How to change the text and image when highlight the row.

Please let me any idea to resolve this two problems.

Comment: in your model set variable to store highlighted info.

Comment: call notifyItemChanged() after your operation

Comment: @Demo Mail.. notifyItemChanged() is not working for my scenario..

Comment: @Divyesh.. Can you give detailed explain?? Plz..

Comment: Your model contains one Boolean field for all items, now in your recyclerview onbindviewholder method, check for boolean value and if it is true then highlight that item. and in your Activity class, when click on item happen get that item position and change that item boolean to true.

Comment: Thanks.. I I'll try and let you know..

Answer (score 2):

You can save click **position** in a variable so whenever new click happens you simply replace your variable value with new clicked position and after that don't forget to use **notifyItemChanged()** ; Now its very simple in your **bindview** check for your selected position and change the background of item.

rough ex.

```
  onClick(){
    highlightedPosition = getLayoutPostion();
    notifyItemChanged();
    }

  onBindView(int position){
    if(highlightedPosition == position){
    higlightedBackground();
    }else{
    normalBackground();
    }
```

Comment: It's working. Is there any other way to use by resource xml? like selector.xml??

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16976534/3863689 if you find this answer helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/xx_sel"`

or
`android:foreground="@drawable/xx_bg_sel"`
I use it to let my album photo item pregress or fouce can has a mask on it.
May it will help you.