# ListView.setSelector(...) won't apply correct background color to selected item

Tags: java, android, listview

Tl;dr: I am using ListView's `setSelector(...)` to change the background color of a selected item, and while the color does change, it picks a default color and not the one I want.

I want to create a ListView that allows just one item to be selected at a time. (Almost) everything works fine, but the selected item is always colored in a default color, no matter what I tried. Here is my code:

**ListView:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/account_picker_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_button" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/account_picker_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/account_picker_list_corner"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/selection_effect"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_picker_divider2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ListView>

    [...]
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**selection_effect.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/highlightColor" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/lightred" android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/lightgreen" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/colorAccentLight" android:state_active="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/buttonColor" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/black" android:state_hovered="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_single="true"/>
</selector>
```

**relevant code in the activity that manages the ListView:**

```
private void createAccountViewAdapter() {
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    ArrayList<Account> al = new ArrayList<>();

    if (accountViewAdapter == null) {
        accountViewAdapter = new AccountPickerViewAdapter(this, al, this);
    }

    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.account_picker_list);
    listView.setSelector(R.drawable.selection_effect);
    listView.setAdapter(accountViewAdapter);

    updateAccountViewAdapter();
}

public void updateAccountViewAdapter() {
    TextView noAccounts = findViewById(R.id.account_picker_no_account);
    ArrayList<Account> al = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!AccountHandler.getAllAccounts().isEmpty()) {
        al = AccountHandler.getAllAccounts();
        noAccounts.setText("");
    } else {
        noAccounts.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.no_accounts));
    }
    accountViewAdapter.refreshItems(al);
}
```

The custom ListView adapter only implements `getView(...)` and does not change the backround color in any way.
As you can see from the statements in the `selection_effect.xml`, I already tried about every combination of possible states android let me use, needless to say, the actual color displayed in the app it not among the ones I defined above. What am I missing?

Edit: Turns out the app was using the default colors of the `AppTheme` I set for the activity in question. After changing the default colors in the `styles.xml`, the selection color was now defaulting to the new color. However, I still don't understand why I can't set a custom color for the selected item.

```
<activity
        android:name=".AccountPicker"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Popup">
</activity>

<style name="AppTheme.Popup" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorAccentLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Edit2: Here is the **AccountPickerViewAdapter** class:

```
public class AccountPickerViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Account> {
ArrayList<Account> accounts;
Activity intent;

public AccountPickerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Account> accounts, Activity intent) {
    super(context, 0, accounts);
    this.intent = intent;
    this.accounts = accounts;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.account_picker_item, parent, false);
    }

    final Account myAccount = getItem(position);

    TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_item_name);
    TextView balance = convertView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_item_balance);
    TextView description = convertView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_item_description);
    Button confirm = convertView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_item_confirm);

    name.setText(myAccount.getName());
    balance.setText(AccountHelper.stringifyBigDec(myAccount.getBalance(), false, true, myAccount.getId()));
    description.setText(myAccount.getDescription());
    /*
    confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AccountHandler.setActiveAccount(myAccount.getId());

            intent.finish();
        }
    });

    confirm.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    */

    return convertView;
}

public void refreshItems(ArrayList<Account> items) {
    this.accounts.clear();
    this.accounts.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post `AccountPickerViewAdapter` class too?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the OP. Mind you, for the time being I just went with not making the items clickable. Then again, it has no relevant code to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra attribute named such as `isSelected` to `Account` class.

```
class Account {
    ... other attributes
    private boolean isSelected;
}
```

In `getView` of `AccountPickerViewAdapter`:

```
final Account myAccount = getItem(position);
if (myAccount.isSelected()) {
    // set selected background
} else {
    // set default background
}
```

When `onItemClick` of the list view set `isSelected` as true of the clicked account item.

Or, for another approach see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that is not really what I'm asking for. WHile your solution, with some work, can replicate Android's `ListView.setSelector(...)` functionality, I want to understand why `setSelector(...)` doesn't work properly in my case. I will edit the OP to make this more clear.