# How to change listview item background color using if condition Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I'm creating an app with listview and I added few values like 101,102 to 110 to the listview. Now I have to change the listview item background colour using edittext. For example if I type 101 and click submit button, background colour of 101 should change. Please help. Please......

Comment: are you using RecyclerView or just LinearLayout?

Comment: I'm using listview only listview please help.....

Answer (score 0):

First Declare the layout of adapter

```
linearlayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

then set color if match the number in onBindViewHolder()

```
if((position.Value())==typedValue){
    holder.linearlayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF003B"));
}
```

Comment: Good, but I'm using only activity_main.xml, inside that I'm using edittext, button and listview. Now I'm able to display number between 101 to 110 using adapter. Now I'm enter 102 on edittext and click the button. 102 item background have to change please help with source code please.....

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
listView.setSelectorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
```

You can see this [[Change background color of selected item on a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976431/change-background-color-of-selected-item-on-a-listview/37248223#37248223])

Comment: I'm not clicking any item, I'm just typing the number on edittext and click the button. To change that particular number background color.....please help me...pleaseee