# ListView Highlight item without user intervention

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I hava listview which is in sidebar. This listview has 5 items and for click on each item an new activity is launched .
So , this sidebar listview also is part of that activity . I cannot use CLick Listener event to highlight listview since each click launches an completely new activity and hence a new view.
The only option seems to be to highlight the item in listview in ONcreate() Event or some other hack.

How can i create an highlight an item in listview when the listview itself is replaced on each click on listview item

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to write a custom list adapter. Extend a custom class from base adapter. The override the getView(...) function. Inside the getView you can check for a condition and then highlight the item/changebackground/etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sidebar `ListView` is the same for each activity, then it should be a simple matter of passing the index of the `ListView` item that was selected to the new activity. Then in the new activity's `onCreate`, highlight the correct item in the `ListView`. I'll leave the implementation up to you but it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: I can do that but where should i set background color ? App crashing if i do that in Oncreate() because apparently the view is not fully formed when i set the background color of listitem.

Comment: @james234 How are you currently doing it? If you google around there are a bunch of different ways of doing it. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview is one of them. What error are you getting? You should be able to make changes to the View in `onCreate()`.