# Listview row color not changed from asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-drawable

I am trying to update color of listview from async task postexecute method.

I am doing `((View) lstChoices.getAdapter().getView(0,null, lstChoices)).setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

But this is not doing anything, but I tried the same in getView method of my custom adapter then it worked, `row.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: you should never manually change the views background, you should be using a selector as the background and use `listview.setItemChecked()`

Comment: I want to update the listview's rows background color inorder to represent the result

Comment: And you can do that with a selector and using setItemChecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not change this that way. All what is related to the row should be handled in adapter. It means that if you changed anything that could influence background color, then all you should do is `notifyDatsetChanged()` which would trigger list redraw. And b/g color should be then changed by adapter.

Comment: So, after notifyDatsetChanged(), the getView method of adapter will be called?

Comment: `notifyDatasetChanged()` tells adapter, well... that data it lists has changed and this would trigger list redraw, because list wants to reflect current data, after the change. And redraw would call `getView()` for each visible row.

Answer (score 0):

A very clearly presented approach to Listview Item Background color changing based on the item's **State** is at [Programmatically select item ListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview-in-android)

Since you are looking for 'postexecute' perhaps changing the Item's State and using that approach can help you get what you are after.