# How to Select ListView Item Programmatically

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

Question: How do I highlight an option in a ListView programmatically?

Background: I have looked at tons of threads for this kind of issue however none seem to work. I have a list view in a fragment that is populated by a list created from a database using a custom adapter. When the fragment is opened I would like one of the items to be selected by default (depending on whether edit mode is 1/enabled), I have the position of this item ready. I currently use the `clientList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)`, and try to highlight the option with `setItemChecked` but it doesn't work.

**Fragment OnCreate**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentActivity faActivity = (FragmentActivity) super.getActivity();
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__client, container, false);

    addJob = (AddJob)getActivity();

    clientList = (ListView) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.listView);

    clientList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    dbHandler = new DraycottDataHandler(super.getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    if (dbHandler.getClientCount() != 0)
        Clients.addAll(dbHandler.getAllClients()); //Loads clients into Client list

    populateList(); //Sets adapter for the listview.


    if(addJob.getEdit() == 1) { //Get edit mode from activity
        NewJobClass editJob = addJob.getEditJob();


        for (int i = 0; i < Clients.size(); i++) {
            ClientClass client = Clients.get(i);

            if (client.getID() == editJob.getClientID()) {
                clientList.setItemChecked(i, true); //Highlight item (doesnt do anything).
            }
        }
    }


    clientList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectedClient = Clients.get(position);
            listener.getClientData(selectedClient);

        }
    });


    return linearLayout;

}
```

**ListView XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.simple.jack.application.Fragment_Client">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="#D3D3D3"
        android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If more code is needed I'd be glad to provide it.

[Similar Question and Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview-in-android)

This question is similar to mine however the answer gives me an InflateException.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The view is not ready at that point, try posting it:

```
linearLayout.post(new Runnable(){
@override
public void run(){
//your code that selects the item
}});
```

or calling it onViewCreated

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `clientList.setItemChecked(i, true);`  is being called. 
Can you try by adding the code to make the selection in `onViewCreated` method.

Comment: Yes the method is called I checked by logging to console inside that loop/if statement. Even just placing `setItemChecked` inside the `onViewCreate` does nothing.