# Android: How to color the 2 TextView in the selected row of a ListView

Tags: android, listview, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm trying to make a Music Player in Android, and yesterday I got the idea to set the currently playing song colored in the ListView.

At the beginning I set that every time I start a song, a new BaseAdapter inflate a layout with 2 TextView (title and artist) and if the song is the same in the MediaPlayer, the 2 TextView become blue.

It was working fine, but i noticed that when I pick a song, the ListView scrolls immediately up because the Adapter is recreated.

Searching the web I found that I could create a new method in the BaseAdapter class, where if I pass the ListView and the song position I could color it, so I would call the setAdapter(songList) only in the onCreate method.

Yeah, but it doesn't work.

-SongAdapter:

```
public void updateData(ListView listView, int position){
    if (MainActivity.isMusicStarted) {
        //These 2 lines of code return a NullPointerException
        songView = (TextView) listView.getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        artistView = (TextView) listView.getSelectedView().findViewById(R.id.song_artist);

        //The following 2 lines, if de-commented, color only the two TextView in the first shown row instead of the selected row
        //songView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
        //artistView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);

        if (position==MusicService.getCurrentSong()) {
            songView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
            artistView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
        else{
            songView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.primary_text_light));
            artistView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.secondary_text_light));
        }
    }
}
```

-MainActivity: (called at the end of a OnCompletitionListener())

```
public static void colorSongSelected(int position){
    songAdapter.updateData(songView, position);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

listview.getSelectedView() return the view corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if nothing is selected.

For more information how to select a item in listview you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview-in-android)