# layout below is getting focused in android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, focus

In my main layout I have a pull to refresh list view and a button at the top, on button click a normal list view appears on top of this main layout, but even after the appearance of this list view, the focus is still with the below main layout.

**what can I do to bring the focus to the list view ?**

Comment: Please post your xml code here

Comment: use tag <requestFocus/> in your listview or through code set the focus of the listview.

Comment: you want whole listview to get focus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing setSelection() for particular item in listView,

CheckOut [set focus on any item of listview in android stack answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168247/set-focus-on-any-item-of-listview-in-android)

Either you have to

Use setSelection to some item :

```
mListView.setSelection(position);
```

OR

focussing you have to use **may not work** :

```
mListView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: it worked after I added clearFocus() for the button with these two statements.. thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the focus

```
button.clearFocus();
```

or in listview request focus

```
listView.requestFocus();
```

Comment: tried it, but every time only one particular item is gettnig focused in the list view.

Comment: by adding one more line listview.setSelection(position), it worked fine.. thank you